# Accidentally hid all columns with a macro, how do I get them back?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I tried clicking the topleft corner to select everything then right-clicking and selecting "Unhide".  It doesn't do anything.

Please help me get my worksheet back!

[image]

This is the macro:

```
Sub HideDetails()
    Range("3:8").Select
    If Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden Then
        Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        ActiveSheet.Buttons("btnToggleDetails").Caption = "-"
    Else
        Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Buttons("btnToggleDetails").Caption = "+"
        Range("A1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I forgot to replace EntireColumn with EntireRow before running it.

Comment: Did you try restarting it? Can you share the macro where you hid it. Click the View tab, and see if Unhide is open (in the WIndow tab), or if split is enabled and see if Arrange All helps

Comment: Reopening did not help, it's the same.  Unhide is not available. I added the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whew, fixed it by manually running the following:

```
Sub Test()
    Range("3:8").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Sub SeeAll()
    Range("1:1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

This should restore **all** columns to visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I hope following examples will help you =)

if its only column A(1)

```
Sub UnhideColumnOne()
  On Error Resume Next 
    Range("1:1").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

I should use if its all columns columns:

```
Sub Unhide_All_Columns() 
    On Error Resume Next 
     'in case the sheet is protected
    ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 
End Sub
```

if you want to unhide all rows:

```
  Sub Unhide_All_Rows() 
        On Error Resume Next 
         'in case the sheet is protected
        ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False 
    End Sub
```

Best regards

xsisec